# MultiversX workspace not setting up on VS code in mac

Tags: blockchain, multiversx

I am trying to set up the [MultiversX VS Code extension](https://github.com/ElrondNetwork/elrond-ide-vscode) in my mac.

After installing the extension from the extensions tab, as instructed to set up a Elrond project I entered `cmd+shift+p` and click on `Elrond setup workspace`. After clicking `yes` to multiple allow requests I am getting the following error:
[image: Elrond: Setup Workspace]

How can this be resolved?